# Call exe while building includes command name and arguments

Tags: c#, build

I need to call an *.exe file inside the Pre-build event and define command and arguments for *.exe. I am try to do it like this :

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>cmd /c D:\...\File.exe commandname -tt="option" -opt="option2"</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

When I have started Rebuild nothing happened. App rebuilded successfully but .exe never called.

**UPD**

I also have tried like this, but `-opt` was null while executing :

```
<PreBuildEvent>call D:\...*.exe generate -opt="option"</PreBuildEvent>
```

Comment: Why are you launching a shell just to run a program?  Why not just run the program?

Comment: Open the project csproj file with notepad to make sure the pre-build event is being reference.  You may need to do a clean build since the intermediate object haven't changed and the dependencies are a function of the object dates.

Comment: @Neil this is only one of my attempts. I tried also `cmd "..exe"` and `call "...exe"`

Comment: @jdweng May be I have incorrect understood you, but build-event defined and exists in `*.csproj`.

Comment: Yes.  All the settings you use in Visual Studio are saved in the csproj.  I find it is easier to look through the csproj then to look through all the menus in VS.  The csproj is text and can be opened with notepad.  I sometime edit the csproj when necessary.  In VS paths are full path names and I like using relative path names so I can keep backups of the project by just copying the root folder.

Comment: @jdweng I have found out that my *.exe file starts correct but without named parameters.

Comment: Try changing from cmd /c  (which is close when done) to cmd /k (stay open).  There may be an error message on the console which will help.

Comment: @jdweng I have used NLog inside exe program, and NLog says that `-opt=` is empty but I expected some string value.

Comment: Normally command line option do not have the equal sign. Try removing the equal sign.

Comment: @jdweng I tried like this : `"*.exe" "commandname" "-opt=option1" "-opt=option2"` and this helped

Answer (score 0):

This variant worked for me:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>"some.exe" "somecommand" "-opt=some option" "-opt2=one more opt"
</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```